# No default route found while sending the packets (scapy)

Tags: python, scapy

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LALGC.jpg)

I need help in this.No route found (scapy) error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `no route found` message is a warning not an error.  This should not be a problem anyway since you're trying to send to 127.0.0.1.  The exception raised is a `PermissionError`.  That's because sending the packet requires the administrator privilege.  On a unix like system you must be logged as root to do this.  This is what I get on my Linux:

```py
>>> send(IP(dst='127.0.0.1'), return_packets=True)
.
Sent 1 packets.
<PacketList: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:1>
```

(Don't post images.  Post code instead.  This makes it easier for SO contributors to help you.)